# Error executing Xilinx ISE Design Suite .bin file

Tags: java

I'm trying to execute a .bin file, specifically "Xilinx ISE Design Suite", and I get this error message:

```
./xsetup: 12: [: 64: unexpected operator
./xsetup: 37: [: unexpected operator
./xsetup: 23: ./xsetup: /tmp/selfgz10129/tps/lnx32/jre/bin/java: not found
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed Java? You can install OpenJDK's JRE using `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`. Please try to run the script again after installing.

Comment: downloaded the Java and still the same problem

Comment: How exactly are you trying to execute it?

Answer (score 4):

This error is because you try to install on unsupported operating systems. From their website:

> Linux Support
>
> • Red Hat Enterprise Workstation 5.8 - 5.10 (32-bit and 64-bit)
>
> • Red Hat Enterprise Workstation 6.4 - 6.5 (32-bit and 64-bit)
>
> • SUSE Linux Enterprise 11 (32-bit and 64-bit)
>
> • Cent OS 6.4 and 6.5 (64-bit)

But the unsupported part comes from the fact that the installer assumes BASH and we use DASH as a shell. This should work:

```
$ cd /bin
$ sudo mv sh sh.old
$ ln -s bash sh
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ chmod +x ./Xilinx_Vivado_SDK_2014.1_0405_1_Lin64.bin
$ sudo ./Xilinx_Vivado_SDK_2014.1_0405_1_Lin64.bin
```

(adjust the file name to your download)

Mind you: this will also turn your machine to the bash shell but that is the consequence of using this. You turn back to the regular Ubuntu setup with:

```
$ cd /bin
$ sudo mv sh.old sh
$ exit
```

[From the xilinx forums](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Installation-and-Licensing/2014-1-installation-on-linux-64-bit/td-p/441558)

Comment: Thanks alot,it works now after changing to BASH using: sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by manually specifying the extract dir:

```
./Xilinx_Vivado_SDK_2014.1_0405_1_Lin64.bin --target Xilinx_Install_temp
```

And then when it fails:

```
cd Xilinx_Install_temp
```

edit xsetup and change first line from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`

save file and run from console:

```
./xsetup
```